# Unauthorized user can access related model in loopback

Tags: node.js, access-token, loopback

I've added a model `MyModel` and extended Client model from `User` model. I've set up relation between `MyModel` and `Client`. A Client can have many MyModel while each MyModel belongs a client.

In Client.json

```
... 
"relations": {
    "myModels": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "MyModel",
      "foreignKey": "createdBy"
    }
  }
...
```

In MyModel.json

```
...
"relations": {
    "client": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Client",
      "foreignKey": "createdBy"
    }
  },
...
```

After setting the relation, I get an endpoints like /clients/:id/myModels and others. The `MyModel` related to the client gets loaded even if the user is not authenticated.

Now I've setup ACL as follow, 
In MyModel.json,

```
...
"acls": [
    {
      "accessType": "*",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
      "permission": "DENY"
    }
  ],
...
```

While trying to get list of `MyModel` related to the client, no authentication check is applied. i.e. The list of `MyModel` gets retrieved even if the user is not authenticated.

I thought I need to add `ACL` to restrict unauthenticated user from accessing the related models. So I tried adding following `ACL` in Client.json

```
    ...
    "acls": [
        {
          "accessType": "*",
          "principalType": "ROLE",
          "principalId": "$unauthenticated",
          "permission": "DENY",
          "property":"__get__myModels"
        }
      ]
    ...
```

but it doesn't change anything.

But if an authenticated user tries the route `/client/:id/mymodels/count`, `Unauthorized User` error is displayed.

What needs to be done to solve this issue?

Comment: Certified to be making the request for this route containing `?access_token=` in the link? If you do not do this you will need a verification function that uses the token generated on the backend side to verify the verification of that request!

Comment: @smachs sorry I don't understand what you're saying...

Answer (score 0):

Please use this configuration.

```
 {
    property: '*', //define your property.
    accessType: '*',
    principalType: 'ROLE',
    principalId: '$authenticated',
    permission: 'ALLOW'
  },
```

Comment: Doesn't this rule only give the authenticated user access to the specified property? How does it affect the permission to the unauthenticated user?...Anyway I tried it and it doesn't work. Any other idea is appreciable....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using dynamic ways with Role and RoleMapping, you can try like this.
Role :

```
 { 
    "name" : "admin", 
    "description" : "admin role", 
    "created" : "2018-02-23T15:48:40.514+0000", 
    "modified" : ISODate("2018-02-23T15:48:40.514+0000")
   }
```

RoleMapping :

```
{ 
    "principalId" : ObjectId("5b06825775abbd45b3f02719"), 
    "roleId" : ObjectId("5a903836876b6f0bbaa64c40"), 
    "principalType" : "USER", 
    "created_by" : "user", 
    "created_at" : ISODate("2018-05-24T09:13:59.352+0000")
}
```

and ACL :

```
{
    "model" : "YourModel",
    "property": 'find', 
    "accessType": '*',
    "principalType": 'ROLE',
    "principalId": 'admin', // depends on role name
    "permission": 'ALLOW'
}
```

and for other property as well like findOne, deleteById etc.

For everyone unauthenticated :

### You can also try like this

```
{ 
    "model" : "YourModel", 
    "property" : "find", 
    "accessType" : "*", 
    "permission" : "DENY", 
    "principalType" : "ROLE", 
    "principalId" : "$everyone"
}
```

For a particular user

```
{ 
    "model" : "YourModel", 
    "property" : "find", 
    "accessType" : "*", 
    "permission" : "ALLOW", 
    "principalType" : "ROLE", 
    "principalId" : "5a817425e09bdb38f9217c20", // user doc id
}
```

Comment: At the moment, I've been using the ACL provided by loopback.

Comment: @20B2 you can also use above in acls section in  model.json file.

Comment: I've tried adding acl in  the Client.json and specifying the model name, but the result is still the same.